# Configure vim to delete blank lines at end of file

Tags: vim

I would like my vim to delete empty lines at the end of a file. Sometimes when I'm dealing with generated text or copy & pasting, I get a file with some blank lines at the end. I generally like to keep things tidy and delete them, but it's a little annoying to do this all the time.

Is there a way I can configure vim to do this automatically? I already have it deleting whitespace characters at the end of lines. I want this for blank lines at the end of files.

Comment: Weird question, maybe… but are you sure that blank line is actually there?

Comment: @romainl yes, because it shows up with its own line number in vim, and there aren't any more line numbers after that.